# Java Recursive function trick

Tags: java, recursion

Could anyone explain the output of this program? Why is the is the second value 7?

Not able to understand recursive function call `go(this)`

```
public class ThisIsTricky {

    int state = 0;

    public ThisIsTricky(int s) {
        state = s;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ThisIsTricky obj1 = new ThisIsTricky(1);
        ThisIsTricky obj2 = new ThisIsTricky(2);

        System.out.println(obj1.go(obj1) + "" + obj2.go(obj2));
    }

    int go(ThisIsTricky thisIsTricky) {
        if (this.state == 2) {
            thisIsTricky.state = 5;

            go(this);
        }
        return ++this.state;
    }

}
```

**Output:-**

```
2 7
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The important thing to notice is that `state` is a member variable, so it is not shared between `obj1` and `obj2`. Each has its own value (1 and 2, respectively).

Why is the output 7 for `obj2`? The condition `(this.state == 2)` is true for `obj2`, so you go recursively into `go(this)`. Now the condition is not true anymore because `state` was changed to 5, so `state` gets incremented. Recursive call ends and you now return to the calling function (after `go(this)`) and `state` gets incremented again. Therefore, 5+1+1 = 7.

Comment: Correct interpretation

Answer (score 1):

The output of the program would come out to be `27` ( without spaces ). This is due to java passing the address of the object variables in the function calls.

1. The first `2` would be the result of the call of `obj1.go(obj1)` which would be an increment in the state value of obj1.
2. The next output would be `7` when `obj2.go(obj2)` is called and as the **obj2's** state value being 2 triggers the `if` statement and changes the state value to `5`.Then the recursive function `go(this)` is called again with the same address of original parameter. This time the `if` statement is not called and the function simply returns an incremented value , that is `6`. The control then returns to the original function and the function returns an increment to that value , that is `7` and it is printed in the output.

Answer (score 1):

'obj1': 'state=1' and '1!=2' so return 1+1= 2.

'obj2' Is easier to understand when you unravel the recursion:

```
State = 2 so we enter the conditional clause:
 Set state=5
 Recursively call to 'go'
    state is 5 and 5!=2. So skip conditional clause
    increment state, state is now 5+1=6
    return 6
Back in the original call to 'go', increment state, state is now 6+1=7
return 7
```

Thus, the output is `27`